# Lost Kotlin support in Intellij Idea 14.1

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I had a android project in Kotlin that worked fine in Idea 14. But on update to 14.1, I seem to have lost support for Kotlin in the IDE. There is no option to create a new Kotlin file on right clicking a package, no syntax highlighting, auto complete etc. whatsoever for Kotlin files. The Kotlin plugin is installed and enabled.

Anyone else facing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Version of the Kotlin-Plugin is installed?

Because it seems like a known bug:
[Latest Kotlin Plugin not compatible with IntelliJ 14.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7113)

Comment: Plugin version is 0.11.91.Idea139Release.1. As suggested in the bug report, let me try reinstalling the plugin.

Comment: Alright. It works fine after reinstalling. The version number changes from 0.11.91.Idea139Release.1 to 0.11.91